# STM32 Timer with output compare

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, bare-metal

I'm using B-L4S5I-IOT01A board (STM32L4S5VIT6) and I'm following bare-metal course, but I'm not able to force my LED to blink when timer expire.

In my board configuration, LED is connected on PB14, and also in documentation I've seen PB14 has TIM1_CH2N uder Alternate Function 1.

```
void initTimerTim1() 
{
  RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM1EN;
  (void)RCC->APB2ENR;

  GPIOB->MODER &= ~(1U << 28);
  GPIOB->MODER |= 1U << 29;

  GPIOB->AFR[1] |= 1U << 24;
  GPIOB->AFR[1] &= ~(1U << 25);
  GPIOB->AFR[1] &= ~(1U << 26);
  GPIOB->AFR[1] &= ~(1U << 27);

  TIM1->PSC = 400 - 1;
  TIM1->ARR = 20000 - 1;
  TIM1->CNT = 0;

  TIM1->CCMR1|=TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_0|TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_1;
  TIM1->CCER|=TIM_CCER_CC2E;
  TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE;   

  TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}


int main() 
{
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1U << 1;
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 1U << 2;

  initTimerTim1();

  while (1){}
}
```

I've checked also some registers and it seems to be configured properly (at least according to my understanding).

```
GPIOB->MODER MODER14 = 0b10 (10: Alternate function mode)
GPIOB->AFRH PIN14 = 0b0001 (0001: AF1)

TIM1->CR1 CEN = 0b1
TIM1->CCER CC2E = 0b1
TIM1->CCMR1_Output O2CM=0b011
```

Is it possible to even achieve this with TIM1 (my course uses TIM2).

Comment: You haven't really shown us how the timer is configured.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Whole codebase (without includes) is above - there is no other code, so all timer configuration is in initTimerTim1() function.

Comment: Voting to close this as typo since it is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIM1_CH2**N** is enabled by TIMx_ENR.CC2**N**E.

Comment: Ohh, it works! Can you elaborate please why CC2NE was used instead CC2E? In my course it was CC2E and can't understand why it was not working before with previous one, just reading registre reference.

Comment: Read description of the CC1NE bit in the TIMx_CCER register description in TIM1/TIM8 chapter of RM; and for the minute details see _Output control bits for complementary OCx and OCxN channels with break feature_ table.